# Error in php please stop it

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$user_name = $_POST['name'];
$user_email = $_POST['email'];
$user_password = $_POST['password'];

if($user_name=='') {
echo "<stript>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
exit();
}

if($user_email=='') {
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email')</script>";
    exit(); 
}

if($user_password=='') {
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter your password')</script>";
    exit();
}
```

IT CANT GO RIGHT HELP MEE!!!...
I CANT FIND OUT WHAT IS MISSING OR WHAT Ive DID WRONG

Comment: Whats the error? What happens and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: after reloading the page it always says 'please enter your email'...did somthing wrong

Comment: Please describe your Problem in more detail

Answer (score 0):

I think "stript" does not exist.
It's why the second alert echo. And use if(!empty($_POST['name']) is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo/spelling mistake,  script

replace

```
 echo "<stript>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
```

with

```
echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
```

Comment: I've use" if(!empty($_POST['name']) " but this pop up  syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\